# Error using neuralnet() function in R, Algorithm returned results of all -.9999

Tags: r, neural-network

I am currently attempting to create an R neuralnet() code that will predict whether a stock will increase (1), decrease (-1), or stay the same (0). I have the closing price for the past 7 days, and the high, low, and opening prices for the last 3 days. Acc is the measure of the return, calculated in excel.
Every time I run this file, my $net.result is always just -.9999999... for all of them.
I am fairly new to R as well.
Please feel free to point out any errors you find. Any assistance with this is appreciated.

f <- neuralnet( Acc ~ c2 + c3 + c4 + h5 + L5 + o5 + c5 + h6 + L6 + o6 + c6 + h7 + L7 + o7 + c7, data = e3, hidden = c(10,5), threshold = 0.01, stepmax = 1e+06, rep = 1, startweights = NULL, learningrate = 0.01, lifesign = "full", lifesign.step = 1000, algorithm = "rprop+", err.fct = "ce", act.fct = "tanh", linear.output = FALSE, exclude = NULL, constant.weights = NULL, likelihood = FALSE )